# Can't decode an improperly encoded string with Ã character

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mojibake

I'm trying to encode this:

```
"LIAISONS Ã  NEW YORK"
```

to this:

```
"LIAISONS à  NEW YORK"
```

The output of `print(ascii(value))` is

```
'LIAISONS \xc3  NEW YORK'
```

I tried encoding in cp1252 first and decoding after to utf8 but I get this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

I also tried to encode in Latin-1/ISO-8859-2 but that is not working too.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `print(ascii(inputvalue))` to help us understand what actual data you have? If you have a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) then there are probably some extra bytes missing for it to be re-coded from UTF-8 (specifically, the `A0` byte in the UTF-8 encoding for `à`, C3 A0).

Comment: Sure Output: 'LIAISONS \xc3  NEW YORK'

Comment: Then you can't go back to UTF-8, the missing byte is already gone.

Comment: oh, that's unlucky, ty for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go from your input value to your desired output, because the data is no longer complete.

If your input value was an actual [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) re-coding from UTF-8 to a Latin encoding, then you'd have *two* bytes for the `à` codepoint:

```
>>> target = "LIAISONS à NEW YORK"
>>> target.encode('UTF-8').decode('latin1')
'LIAISONS Ã\xa0 NEW YORK'
```

That's because the UTF-8 encoding for `à` is C3 A0:

```
>>> 'à'.encode('utf8').hex()
'c3a0'
```

In your input, the `A0` byte (which doesn't map to a printable character in most Latin-based codecs) has been filtered out somewhere. You can't re-create it from thin air, because the `C3` byte of the UTF-8 pair can precede any number of other bytes, all resulting in valid output:

```
>>> b'\xc3\xa1'.decode('utf8')
'á'
>>> b'\xc3\xa2'.decode('utf8')
'â'
>>> b'\xc3\xa3'.decode('utf8')
'ã'
>>> b'\xc3\xa4'.decode('utf8')
'ä'
```

and you can't easily pick one of those, not without additional natural language processing. The bytes 80-A0 and AD are all valid continuation bytes in UTF-8 for this case, but none of those bytes result in a printable Latin-1 character, so there are at least 18 different possibilities here.